# Object inside for loop returns empty (javascript)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, sum, append

I am trying to sum the numbers returned by the for loop but for some reason, I can't append anything to my local variables and save them. Could someone please point out what I'm doing wrong as I'm new to Javascript? I am trying to log the total price as I query an array of data, one by one. Thanks

```
  Parse.Cloud.define('test', function(req, res) {
  var items = [req.params.ids];
  var totalPrice = 0.0;
  var temp = [];
  var temp2 = [];
    for (var x = 0; x < items[0].length; x++) {
    var items2 = Parse.Object.extend("Items");
    var query = new Parse.Query(items2);
    var totalp = [];
    query.get(items[0][x], {
      success: function(result) {   
          var ob = result.get("Price");
          console.log(ob); // It logs the Float value and works fine until here
        totalPrice = totalPrice + ob;
        totalp.push(ob);
      },
      error: function(obj, err) {
       res.error(err);
      }
    });
      temp.push(totalp); //pushes empty array
      console.log(totalp); //returns []
    }
  console.log(temp); //returns [ [], [] ]
  res.success(totalPrice); // returns 0
});
```

Comment: The success callback is asynchronous, e.g. executed after your loop has run. This is also observable by the order of the console log output - the float value will be logged **after** the other entries.

Comment: You will have to wait on all of the asynchronous calls to complete before you can do `res.success(totalPrice)` — currently that's being returned before the AJAX requests are even sent, never mind have returned and incremented the price.

Comment: @LiamGray This makes sense, but now I'm even more confused. How can I wait for the asynchronous call to finish? Could you please show me how it's done?

Comment: @LiamGray Can this be done using `then` ?